# very simple query PostgreSQL takes long time in New Relic?

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, newrelic

I don't have a enough experience in PostgreSQL  with .net core 2.0, i am facing an issue in performance there are simple queries i run from my app (.net core 2.0 web api ) against PostgreSQL  AS ADO Queries .
in new relic  it consume a lot of time why this behavior and how can i solve it 
 Please your responses are highly appreciated

example of slowest queries  is  (id is the primary key )

```
Select status from Tasks where id =@id
```

[image]